# SQL Server Management Studio connects to Azure SQL Database from Windows 10 but does not connect from VM on Windows Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, azure-sql-database, ssms, windows-server-2012-r2

I use absolutely the same credentials and default settings to connect to a Azure SQL Database from my virtual machine with Windows Server 2012 R2 as those I use on my laptop with Windows 10. I do so with the same version of SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

I added both machines' IP's to the Azure SQL DB firewall rules.

The firewall on the VM is off.

I get perfect connection from my laptop with Win10, but whenever I'm on that VM with Windows Server I get this message in my SSMS:

### `Connect to Server`

`Cannot connect to <my_database>.database.windows.net.`

---

`ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:`

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10061)`

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10061&LinkId=20476

---

`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

---

What should I do to connect to that database from my VM with Windows Server? I googled a lot, tried some things like adding outbound rules to the Windows Server firewall for TCP/UDP/ports and trying different protocols in SSMS, but I'm out of ideas now.

Comment: Are you able to ping (ping -a) your SQL Azure server from the VM? If that is successful, are you able to telnet your SQL Azure Server using the ip address received from the ping command? Telnet IP 1433

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo How do I ping my SQL Azure server? I just tried to run `ping <server>.database.windows.net` in the command prompt, but it returns `Pinging westeurope1-a.control.database.windows.net [some_IP] with 32 bytes of data:` and then `Request timed out` 4 times **on both of the machines (VM _and_ laptop)**. The final line of the returned message says `Ping statistics for <IP>: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is resolved. The problem was that only the inbound port 1433 was open for that virtual machine. After opening the outbound port 1433 for connection with my Azure server everything is working fine.

I know I wrote in the question that firewall on the VM was off, but I got information on that with the wf.msc command which was not relevant (there's a higher level firewall that is managed by system administrators).

Comment: I've just run into same issue. Can you please elaborate what do you mean with `opening the outbound port 1433 for connection with my Azure server`? Thanks.

Comment: I've created in- and out-bound rule to allow port 1433 but still can not connect.

Comment: Using fidler I've find out all connections from my VM ends at proxy server with http 407. I believe I can solve this by myself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is then caused by the lack of basic connectivity from VM to SQL Azure. Make sure the virtual NIC card is mapped to a physical network card (WIFI or Ethernet) and is not configured NAT, Local Host Only or Private Network.

[This](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sql-azure-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide/) article may be useful.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: The link helped me with `ping` and `telnet` commands. 

So after doing `telnet <IP> 1433` I got this  message: 

`Connecting To <IP>...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed`

Comment: Is the virtual NIC on the VM mapped to a physical NIC on the physical machine? Please examine the settings of the VM? What virtualization software you are using? Virtual Box? Hyper-V? VMware Player/Workstation?

Comment: I have no idea how to answer those: "Is the virtual NIC on the VM mapped to a physical NIC on the physical machine? Please examine the settings of the VM?" I am using RDP (the standard Windows program for accessing remote desktop).

Comment: On what software is installed that virtual machine? You get connected using RDP but that virtual machine should be installed on a virtualization software. What is the name of the virtualization software that is used to host that virtual machine?

Comment: This question was just resolved. The problem was that only the inbound port 1433 was open for that virtual machine. After opening the outbound port 1433 for connection with my Azure server everything is working fine. I know I wrote previously that firewall on the VM was off, but I got information on that with the `wf.msc` command which was not relevant (there's some higher level firewall that is managed by system administrators). Thanks for your insights!